# Training went longer than expected due to equipment not working. Should I invoice the extra time?

Tags: contractors, invoices, tech-support

I work as a contractor. The client provided me with specialized equipment. There was a training video conference call. In it, there were 2 instructors and about 3 or 4 other students. During the training my equipment did not work properly. The instructors had to get someone else to join the call to fix my issue after everyone else had left. As a result the call took an hour longer than scheduled.

Should I invoice for the extra time?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: What is (roughly) the scope of the assignment? It's different if you've got an estimated 20 hours of work vs. 6 months of work from them.

Comment: @morsor only reason I can think for the down votes is the answer to this should be in the contract.  The contract should state what is considered billable.  If it says time spent in training is billable then all time is billable vs if it has allotted 1 hour for training and it took two hours the second hour is it not billable.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it probably depends how your billing agreement is set up. If it's strictly per hour, and you worked an extra hour, then you bill an extra hour. If training is separate, then this may or may not be considered as part of that, depending on the exact terms, or this may fall under some other part of the agreement (if the contract leaves this ambiguous, then that would likely be something for lawyers to argue about).

Comment: @BernhardBarker but that sounds like a perfect answer that helps others with the same issue (real or just thinking about how to handle it if it comes up) to know how to handle such situations.

Comment: @FrankHopkins But checking your contract is the first thing you should do if you have any work-related question that could in any way be relevant to it (especially when that question is explicitly about the terms of your contract).

Comment: @BernhardBarker I get that, but obviously not everyone else. Also not every contract has this covered (e.g. if you are working as a contractor and you didn't put that in because you didn't know that you better had it in). And btw. a lot of questions here could ultimately be answered with "read the contract" or "read the company guidebook" that doesn't make the questions invalid/unhelpful. I would agree that the question could be improved by making it more generally applicable, but I fail to see why a question with a presumably "easy" answer would not be valid.

Comment: @BernhardBarker and since OP is a contractor and might have written their contract themselves there might not be a particularly clear section covering this. It could just say "work is paid by the hour", then it would be valid to ask for the "typical" interpretation regarding such corner cases (how likely billing is enforceable/well received). But to me having at least one question regarding "bill or not bill unclear time" that is answered with "look into the contract" would be helpful for the site, so people find it and go looking in their contract.

Comment: @FrankHopkins Where do we draw the line? Do we need a line? Would it be on-topic for someone to ask how much they get paid, or how many leave days they get? I'm not being facetious nor employing a slippery slope, it's a serious question. To me the line would be pretty much anything that's written in your contract. A slight variant of this, e.g. "would fixing equipment count as 'hours worked'", might be on-topic for me (and it might also be that I'm simply nitpicking by differentiating this from that, and I'd probably prefer a more general "what is included in 'hours worked'" canonical Q&A)

Comment: @BernhardBarker I would consider all your examples in principle valid (if there is demand, which would be kinda proven by someone asking - bots etc aside), because space is cheap, they can help beginners who have no clue (say people that just start their work life and have no clue how it all works), are not rubbish questions that make no sense and broad enough to help others and to outline the basics. Why would this be *only* for experts who already know the basics? Anyway, I've made my point regarding this question and the rest is more a meta discussion. Have a nice day,evening, night.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> Should I invoice for the extra time?

If you are an independent contractor, you should invoice for the entire time you spent.

If you work for a contracting agency, you should ask your boss. The agency owns the client relationship, and should make this decision with their knowledge of the client's overall situation in mind.

Answer (score 44):

Yes as you worked an extra hour. That hour was not due to your fault.

Comment: Does the fault really matter? As long as the OP was putting forth a best effort, I'm not sure it makes a difference if the issue was due to a mistake on their part or if it was an issue they could not have solved themselves. Either way, they worked the extra hour.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie - It was an after though. I though it might sweeten the pill for the poster to charge

Comment: @NuclearHoagie If they are a contractor, the fault does matter. If they are an employee, no.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie He's talking about invoicing the **CUSTOMER**. If I was a customer and my mechanic decides to charge for time waiting for component to arrive I would NOT WANT TO PAY. I know the mechanic probably had to stay at the workshop longer while waiting for the part but he is NOT working on my car at that time. The OP is a contractor, a business providing service to a customer.

Comment: @slebetman The difference here is that the client/customer supplied the faulty equipment. If you send your car to the mechanic after welding the hood shut, you can bet they'll charge you for the time it took them to get it open.

Answer (score 15):

How much are you billing?

If it's just a one off, I would not bother.  If it's a frequent occurrence then yes.

You do not want to be known as the difficult contractor who nickels and dimes.  You may get your extra hour this time, but is it worth the damage to your reputation and harming the chance at renewing your contract?

Comment: They also do not want to be known as the pushover contractor who undervalues their work.

Comment: @Theodore The "difficult" contractor never hears from them again; the "pushover" gets the work and can deal with being pushed-over as it comes up. So it depends on whether they're currently turning away clients, or trying to get more.

Comment: @OwenReynolds That's correct, but if you're undervaluing your work, you go into bankruptcy faster the busier you are.

Comment: You're not being a "difficult contractor" by accurately charging for hours you actually worked and it wouldn't damage your reputation with decent companies (although not all companies are decent). In fact, in some contexts I may actually respect someone *more* if they accurately bill me compared to having them omit some charges.

Comment: If you choose to let it go, you could consider explicitly waiving it instead of not billing at all.  This conveys a sense of "I'm doing you a favor", where they might not be thinking about it that way.  Even if they disagree about whether it should be considered a favor, it may be worthwhile for them to see that you are looking at it that way, lest they assume that you're just ok with giving away the extra time.

Answer (score 6):

You said that "during the training, **my** equipment did not work properly."

The answer to your question properly depends on who provided "your" equipment.  (Your question statement was ambiguous; I'm surprised no-one else mentioned that.)  If *they* provided it, you're justified in charging for the extra time its failure necessitated, though of course the aforementioned concerns and caveats apply, and you may think better of it.  If *you* provided the failed equipment, and there's no clause in your contract covering that eventuality, most reasonable people would begrudge your fee for the extra hour.

Either way, if you *don't* charge, John Bollinger's suggestion is a good one, mentioning the time, and that you're not charging for it, can gain you goodwill.

Comment: The second sentence of the question is "The client provided me with specialized equipment.", so I don't think there's any ambiguity over who provided it.

Comment: The "**my**" denotes physical possession, not ownership. This is made evident by "The client provided me with specialized equipment."

Answer (score 2):

Was it your fault?

**No**

Bill them for the extra hour.

**Yes**

Don't bill for the extra hour.

Comment: Really is this simple.